# Place div under div

Tags: html, css, position

Probably a really simple solution.

I have two container divs

```
.topwrap{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    background:#00C;
```

}

and

```
.lowerwrap{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    background:#00C;
}
```

but .lowerwrap for some unknown reason keeps staying above .topwrap. Within those two containers are images etc that are positioned correctly. Its just that I cant get .lowerwrap to go directly below .topwrap

Sorry if I havent explained it all properly.

Kind regards

(full code)

```
/*---------------------------- Header ----------------------------*/
.headerwrap{
    position:relative;
}
.header{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
.header img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    width:15%;  
    top:5%;
    left:43%;
    z-index:10;
}
.logo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/*---------------------------- Main Work ----------------------------*/
.menu{
    width:100%; 
    top:0px;
    z-index:200;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:1%;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
li a{
    color:#A11D22;
    transition:300ms;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#999;
}
.menutxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:2.5vw;
    color:#A11D22;
    font-weight:bold;
    z-index:3000;
}
/*----------------------------Top ----------------------------*/
.topwrap{
    position:relative;
    background:#00C;
    height:auto;
}
.face{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    right:15%;
    background:#00C;
}
.face img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.speech{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    right:15%;
    background:#00C;
}
.speech img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
/*----------------------------Lower----------------------------*/
.lowerwrap{
    position:relative;
    background:#00C;
}
```

```
<!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
    <div class="headerwrap">
        <div class="header">
                <img src="images/header.png" />
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" />
            </div><!--close logo-->
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menutxt">
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="manga.html">CONTACT</a></li>                 
                </ul>
            </div><!--close menu-->
        </div><!--close header-->
    </div><!--close headerwrap-->
 <!--===================================================Top===================================================!-->
    <div class="topwrap">
        <div class="face">
            <img src="images/face.png"/>
        </div><!--close face-->
        <div class="speech">
            <img src="images/speech.png"/>
        </div><!--close speech-->
    </div><!--close topwrap-->
<!--===================================================Lower===================================================!--> 
    <div class="lowerwrap">
        <p>dsadsadasd</p>
    </div><!--close topwrap-->   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to place the div under the other div?

Comment: by under do you mean under on the z plane or the y plane?

Comment: are you trying to place lowerwrap "behind" topwrap or "below" topwrap?

Comment: im meaning directly under. Not in terms of on top (z-index). The .topwrap must be positioned above and the .lowerwrap must go directly under. But for some reason it doesn't want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use top, how about this:

```
.topwrap{
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    background:#EEE;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

 .lowerwrap{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    background:#555;
    display: block;
}
```

I created a simple fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6xj5snv2/

Comment: tried removing the top:100px; from both. But still seems to be persistent in not going below the div that is above it.

Comment: is the site live so we can have a look at it? Do you have other items that are absolutely positioned?

Comment: to add to this. I started playing with adding random text. It seems to place itself below that random text but not the images within those containers. Its strange

Comment: My logo is absolute. But thats positioned above .topwrap and within its own container which is relative

Comment: can you show your actual divs and how you are displaying the images? also try setting the height of the divs.

Comment: can you add the relevant html though too

Comment: Added all the html. I tried also changing the height of the .topwrap with px but that didnt seem to work. played with vw as i needed the site to be able to adjust to phone and tablet sizes and the position stays below the first div. But still strange it doesnt go below on default

Comment: would seem that my images still shift it in a weird way. Cause now the divs are side by side. So may have to play with image positioning etc

Comment: if you want them beneath each other use "display: block;"

Comment: added display block to the images, the lowerwrap still floats above.

Comment: Never mind got it working. Think it wasn't happy with one of my lines of code. But works perfectly now. Thanks man!

Comment: glad you got it working, if an answer fixed your problem please mark it as the answer.  If not, please add your own answer to help someone who may have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use z-index to achieve that. keep in mind that the div with the higher z-index will be on top so i suggest to add z-index:2 for .topwrap and z-index:1 .lowerwrap you can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: If creating them in sequential order and both are positioned relatively the z-index isn't be needed as the second div would be placed on top by default.

Comment: im aware of the z-index. But doesnt that mean I would still have to adjust the the position using top? I have a headerwrapper directly above those two wrappers but had no problems with it going above or anything?